# HDD light blinking every second

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, power-management, svchost

some people asked about it already, but in my case it isn't a problem with the CD drive (it happens even when I take it out). I run procmon from SysInternals for a while and found out, that svchost.exe makes some registry calls to following keys:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\

I did a fresh Windows 7 Pro 64bit installation few days ago, because my old HDD died. The new HDD is a 1TB 2,5" HDD from Samsung. The laptop is a Thinkpad T400 2767-B44 with 8GB RAM. I never had this strange behaviour until now.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Occasional HD access is normal though. Are you sure it does it _every_ second all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ThinkPad's power manager does that. But it's not a problem. HDDs are made to work, for years.

It's not the work that kills them. It's the power cycle. If you are using your laptop plugged in (remember, always remove your battery), turn off the automatic HDD shutdown feature.

It can be done via the [Power Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOTRa.jpg) (Windows) or via Lenovo's [Power Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/543k4.jpg).

Comment: Can you provide a link to something explaining the value of always removing your battery when running a laptop plugged into A/C power?

Comment: That advice is probably overkill. The main point is that it's not good for a battery to stay fully charged for a long time, so if you're going to keep your laptop constantly plugged in for days or weeks, then you might consider removing the battery. Alternatively, I just flip the switch on my power strip at night and let my machine discharge its battery a bit in sleep mode. Here's a link that discusses the main ideas: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: Well... it's a personal observation and long hours of reading. Basically, you charge your battery all the time. Even if it's intelligent, you are basically killing it. Also: The heat won't do any good. Trust me, I tried it with many batteries. Taking it out is much better than leaving it in your computer all the time.

Comment: Of course this doesn't apply if you just want to keep your laptop for a year or two. Or if you want to buy a new battery every year. (Most batteries died within a year (or lost a lot of percentage) when we kept them in the machines.)

Comment: I let my battery discharge, without removing it, every so often. However, I can't agree with removing it because there is a not-insignificant benefit to having a battery when there's a power failure. Can you prove that removing it is, in fact, better?